# Meteor - error after upgrading to 1.4

Tags: meteor

I was working in a project in Meteor 1.3 and today I upgraded to 1.4 and when i try to run the project after running `meteor reset` I get the following error:

```
  While loading plugin `compileScss` from package `fourseven:scss`:

   /Users/mazinalmaskari/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.2.1.1.xb5zda++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScss.os.osx.x86_64/npm/compileScss/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22:11:
   `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
   at getBinding
   (/Users/mazinalmaskari/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.2.1.1.xb5zda++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScss.os.osx.x86_64/npm/compileScss/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22:11)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (/Users/mazinalmaskari/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.2.1.1.xb5zda++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScss.os.osx.x86_64/npm/compileScss/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:188:23)
   at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
   at Module.load
   (/Users/mazinalmaskari/.meteor/packages/meteorhacks_npm/.1.5.0.m71zaz++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.initializing-npm-support.os/npm/initializing-npm-support/node_modules/node-echo/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (/Users/mazinalmaskari/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.bf0k83++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1633:22)
   at Object.require
   (/Users/mazinalmaskari/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.bf0k83++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1607:31)
   at <runJavaScript-18>:15:16
   at <runJavaScript-18>:151:4
   at <runJavaScript-18>:158:3


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

And when i remove the package `fourseven:scss` i get the following error:

```
While processing files with stylus (for target web.browser):
   packages/ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/accounts_ui.styl: Stylus compiler error: accounts_ui.styl:85:2
   81| }
   82| .btn-Twitter{
   83|     color: white;
   84|     background-color: #4099FF;
   85| }
   --------^
   86| 
   87| 

   fs.exists is not a function


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Any advice on what should i do here please? is there a way to downgrade to meteor 1.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the problem fixed by executing the following steps:

`meteor remove fourseven:scss`

`meteor add fourseven:scss@=3.8.1`'

for the second problem, I has to move stylus package and add it again because for some reason downloading `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` doesn't come with the latest version of `stylus`

`meteor remove stylus`

`meteor add stylus@=2.513.4`

Comment: Thanks. I think it was mainly teh issue with adding stylus

Answer (score 0):

First try running a `meteor reset` (warning: this will wipe your local Mongo DB).

If that doesn't work, with the `fourseven:scss` package added to your project, try:

```
cd yourproject
npm uninstall node-sass
meteor npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

Comment: the problem still exist even after implementing your solution -_-

Comment: yes i did run `meteor reset` first as it was saying in the terminal. sorry i should have mentioned it in my question, am editing it now

Answer (score 0):

Try running your app as root

```
$ sudo meteor
```